# Unit test fails with "Docker API responded with status code=ProxyAuthenticationRequired, response=Please run 'docker login'"

Tags: .net, docker, testcontainers

I have the following XUnit test, using the Testcontainers lib for .NET (note that I have removed most of the test class, leaving just the part that is relevant to this question.)

```
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Builders;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Containers;
using Xunit;

namespace Property.SERVICE.UnitTests
{
    public class TestApiContainerTests : IAsyncLifetime
    {
        private readonly IContainer _container;

        public TestApiContainerTests()
        {
            var foo = CommonDirectoryPath.GetSolutionDirectory();

            var futureImage = new ImageFromDockerfileBuilder()
                .WithDockerfileDirectory(foo, "src")
                .WithDockerfile("Dockerfile")
                .Build();

            futureImage.CreateAsync();

            _container = new ContainerBuilder()                
                .WithImage(futureImage)                
                .WithPortBinding(8080, true)                
                .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(r => r.ForPort(8080)))                
                .Build();
        }        
    }
}
```

When I let this code run, it gets to the part where it builds the container, using the custom image I have defined. But the test fails with the error...

> Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException Docker API responded with status
> code=ProxyAuthenticationRequired, response=Please run 'docker login'

I tried to resolve this by running `docker login` in a terminal window, which succeeded...

> docker login

> Authenticating with existing credentials... Login

> Succeeded

When I re-ran the unit test, I got the same error as before.

Does anyone know how to get around this please?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your Dockerfile?

In a Dockerfile, you can add a line like this before the line that starts the operation that fails:

```
RUN docker login registry_url -u username -password
```

Where registry_url is the initial part of the image tag, username and password are your credentials

---

.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be able to try this out on Monday, when I am back in work.